# workling & RabbitMQ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rabbitmq, workling

Hi For my project I would like to run some jobs in background using workling (publish some data to the queue) but I'm getting errors while trying to configure my app (unitialized constant MemCache) I'm using Fedora 13 + ruby enterprise edition My questions are

Has anybody worked with workling recently ? Was everything fine ?

Did you try to run "script/workling_client start"? Did you get any errors?

Can someone suggest some alternative to workling ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the bottom of `development.rb` added

```
require 'memcache'
#Workling::Remote.dispatcher = Workling::Remote::Runners::StarlingRunner.new

Workling::Remote.invoker = Workling::Remote::Invokers::EventmachineSubscriber
Workling::Remote.dispatcher = Workling::Remote::Runners::ClientRunner.new
Workling::Remote.dispatcher.client = Workling::Clients::AmqpClient.new
```